# Wishlist Configure Grouped Product

Tags: magento2, layout, wishlist, grouped-products

So I have a grouped product available on my site everything is working fine but when I add a grouped product in my wishlist and edit it. My changes in **catalog_product_view_type_grouped** are not rendering, the layout is all over the place. Can you guys explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer,

Wishlist grouped configure has an XML identifier. which is **wishlist_index_configure_type_grouped**. Just update your layout there.